# Mass update Contacts with associated Account information

Tags: data, update

For organizational purposes, we categorize each account (mid-market, enterprise, agency, etc). We've only had this information at the account level, but recently we've found it necessary to add this field to the contact level.

Is there a way to mass update each contact in an account with this information so that my reps don't have to do so individually?

Comment: Is it going to be maintained separately from the account? You could create a formula field otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Since Contact should have the category of related account, it would be better if you create this field as a formula field in contact to pull value from account and display instead of creating it as an editable field in Contact.

If you create it as formula, you will not need to mass update also.